# including xml file in another xml file

Tags: php, xml, doctrine, propel

In PHP, it's possible to include 1 php file in another php.

Is there something similar for xml files.

The xml file is a database schema (for Propel), and some tables I plan to use in more than one project. I'd prefer to create 1 xml file and include when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML is a tree model - so you'll need to specify at least on which level you want to insert the snippet. A kind of workaround for XML includes with PHP is presented in this forum post:

- http://webprocafe.com/javascript-libraries/2964-can-i-include-extendible-markup-language-file-within-another-extendible-markup-language-file.html#post18163

Snippet copied for reference:

```
<?php header('Content-Type:text/xml'); ?>
<markers>
<?php include("moredata3.xml"); ?>
<?php include("moredata2.xml"); ?>
</markers>
```

Comment: Thanks miku, I'll look at it and see if it's what I'm looking for.